# How to compare strings in C without hard coding the increments?

Tags: c, string-comparison, strtok, strcmp, strstr

I have a buffer that holds a string from a CSV file that I opened and read. I split the string up by using `strtok()` and split on the " , ".  So now my string looks like this:

```
char buff[BUFFER_SIZE] = "1000" "CAP_SETPCAP" "CAP_NET_RAW"
```

I want to make comparisons now for each section of the string, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work. I want to be able to do it without hard coding anything meaning I don't want to assume how many spaces I need to move over. For example to start at CAP_SETPCAP I don't want to have to put `buff+5`. Anybody know a better way to handle this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

       FILE *fp = fopen("csvtest.csv", "r");
       char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];


       fgets(buff, 1024, fp);
       char *csvData = strtok(buff, ",");
       while(csvData != NULL){
             csvData = strtok(NULL, ",");
       }

      int i;
      while(buff[i] != '\0'){
         strcmp(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW")
         printf("Match found");
         i++;
      }

      //or I wanted to do string comparison, but I kept getting
      //segmentation fault (core dumped)

      char *found;
      found = strstr(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW");
      printf("%s\n", found);

      fclose(fp);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth you don't check the result of your `fgets` call.

Comment: If these are packets you probably want to set the buffer size to be in line with the expected packet size, like ~1500 bytes, not 1024. Additionally if you have a constant for your `BUFFER_SIZE` then please *use it*, don't just hard-code 1024 all over the place.

Comment: This code also appears to have numerous crippling syntax errors, like the `if (strcmp(...)` is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: I copied it by hand, I was just trying to show the process.

Comment: I did check the result of the fgets as well I left that out because once again i copied by hand

Comment: Note that your `while (buff[i] ...)` loop will run forever if there's no match, so it's bound to jam eventually.

Comment: If this isn't the code you're actually using that's going to make debugging your actual code a lot harder.

Comment: Doesn't `strstr(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW");` find what you are searching for? Does the segfault occur before it?

Comment: no the segfault occurs during that. I commented everything out and just ran the strstr() and it won't work

Comment: I think you need to do the `strstr` on `csvData` into the loop `while(csvData != NULL){` or not use strtok at all

Comment: What if you substitute the print after `strstr` with `printf("%s\n", found? found : "NULL");` ?

Comment: So I commented everything out except" char *found, found = strstr(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW");, printf("Match found: %s\n", found. but it prints to the screen "CAP_NET_RAW" and "CAP_SYS_ADMIN".

Comment: I use a state machine to parse csv files like 20 lines of code, strok wont work as commas can be part of the field, plus can segfault just lke the other C lib calls,  but if you assume thats it I would still just parse through it in a  one line loop, either make a list of field ends in another array or copy each field to another array/string as you go.   and to see what I am talking about put some commas and quotes in various fields then save as to a csv file...quotes are the key moreso than commas, but see what you see...

Comment: if parsing is not your problem but dealing with the fields that is another story I always operate per field before I fetch the next...YMMV

Comment: `CAP_SYS_ADMIN"`? There's not such string in your example. Is it after `"CAP_NET_RAW"`? If yes, it is expected, since the found is a substring starting with `"CAP_NET_RAW"`'til the end of buff.

Comment: I apologize it printed CAP_NET_RAW and CAP_SETPCAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has three different sections. Lets analyze them:

---

### 1. The `strtok` section

You get the data from the file and then you iterate on `strtok`:

```
fgets(buff, 1024, fp);
char *csvData = strtok(buff, ",");
while(csvData != NULL){
    csvData = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

You seem not interested in what you found in the different positions: in fact `csvData` is always overwritten with the last token. And at last it is equal to `NULL`.

The only thing you get is having the commas in the original array buff overwritten with `'\0'`. Printing `buff` you will only see `"1000"`, because after this substring there is the string terminator placed by `strtok`.

---

### 2. Searching `"CAP_NET_RAW"`

You now iterate on `buff[i]` until the string terminator. But the string terminator is after the first substring `"1000"`!

```
int i;
while(buff[i] != '\0'){
    strcmp(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW")
    printf("Match found");
    i++;
}
```

Furthermore you search for `CAP_NET_RAW`, but even without the inner-terminators-issue, the comparison would never succeed. That's because **(1)** the string actually present in buff is `"CAP_NET_RAW"` (with double quotes); **(2)** that token is the last of the row, an it sitll will have the trailing `'\n'` (`fgets` doesn't remove it).

By the way: I copied the code after your edit, and now there's no check on `strcmp()` return value. I suppose it is a typo. **Note**: `strcmp` returns 0 if the string match.

---

### 3. The `strstr` attempt

Finally you look for the string using the `strstr` function. That's a clever idea. But as already said before, buff doesn't contain it. Well, the buffer actually do contain it, but string utilities will stop at the first `'\0'` they found.

```
  char *found;
  found = strstr(buff, "CAP_NET_RAW");
  printf("%s\n", found);
```

So `found` will be NULL, and dereferencing a NULL pointer (that's what `%s` tells printf to do) will lead to a segmentation fault.

---

### 4. Conclusions

As a very simple way to find the only string you care of, I suggest to use only `strstr`, without using strtok before. Alternatively you can still use strtok, but saving tokens in different strings so that you can access them later.

Comment: I read the buffer data in from a csv so it actually originally looked like this: 1000,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_NET_RAW but yes you're right I can't ever get passed the 1000 part of the string when trying to print it back and yes the found returns null.

Comment: So no, double quotes in your original string? I guessed it from your sample line. Well, in that case just ignore those statements.

Comment: no double quotes, I was just trying to show seperation, I can see how that is confusing

Comment: I got strstr to work when I put it before strtok(). Thank you.

Comment: @ldd12345 `%s` tells `printf`:  _"The argument corresponding to this format is a string (a pointer to char). Copy to the output all the characters it points to until you find '\0'"_. Resolving the address contained into a pointer in order to read its contents is said "dereferencing" the pointer.